# How to execute a applescript from php

Tags: php, applescript

Anyone know how to tell php execute a applescript?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can run the program `osascript` via PHP's [exec() function](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) and pass AppleScript code or a file:

```
exec('osascript -e \'tell app "iTunes" to play\'');
exec('osascript path/to/script');
```